# can I make/build VB6 (aka classic Visual Basic) exe file in incremental, fast manner?

Tags: compiler-construction, vb6, linker

I probably am not the first one to observe that VB6 "run with full compile" is fast and nice (hence obviously an incremental, compile what is needed process) whereas the Make exe takes a long time. Sometimes way too long, especially when I have no choice but to test and troubleshoot specifically the behavior of the executable and its standalone process rather than debug version running under IDE process.

So, is there any compiler option or other magic that would transition the make into fast, incremental mode where it would compile the changed modules and then link them with the precompiled other stuff?

Or is this agonizingly slow make actually a matter of slow linker rather than module compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Go into the Project|Properties... dialog.  Select the Compile tab.  Choose Compile to P-Code.

Compiling to native code involves two compiler passes and then a link pass.  I'm not sure why this seems slow to you unless you've never compiled large programs using other languages.